# ViewModels for CRUD application

Tags: java, android, android-viewmodel

I don't know how to properly split code to separate views/viewmodel in android CRUD application. The items are stored in database and accessed using GreenDao.

- I have FragmentA with recyclerView which display all items from database (their names).
- I have FragmentB which is opened when user click RecyclerView row and contains details of the item.
- I have multiple additional fragments which are multi step forms because there is too much data to enter, so I decided to split the form into multiple fragments. And also if user decide to edit existing item, the form should be pre-filled with existing data.

My question is: is it better to create one ViewModel handling that all so there won't be problem with sharing data between fragments (but it might me a bit messy), or it is better to create separate ViewModels for: FragmentA, FragmentB and FormFragments? But in that case how should I pass data e.g. if user click edit button in DetailsFragment? Then the item should be passed to FormsViewModel to pre-fill the form. And also if the user create new item, the list in FragmentA should be updated.

Thanks